# Develop installable button or form across Salesforce?

Tags: apex

I think what I want to develop might be what you would call a "plugin", but that term is already used in the Salesforce world for the CLI sfdx plugins, and Flows. So I'm having a hard time searching for documentation about what I'm trying to do, or to find out if it's even possible.

What I want to do is to develop a button that a salesforce org can have appear wherever they want in Salesforce, not just inside of a custom AppExchange app. For example, suppose I'm on the Contacts tab, and I select a Contact. I would like to have a custom button that opens a modal or page that pulls info from the instance of the Contact object and displays it. Is that possible? If so, where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Global Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_global.htm&type=5).

> You can add global quick actions to almost any page that supports actions. Use global actions to let users log call details, create or update records, or send email, all without leaving the page they’re on. Global create actions enable users to create object records, but the new record has no direct relationship with other records.

Once you create an action, it can be added to almost any type of record page. They can be installed as part of an AppExchange app, deployed with Unlocked Packages, deployed with Change Sets, etc. Check out the documentation on how to develop and deploy Global Actions.